# How to update live data value in android

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-paging

I am using liveData in my application. I do a DB Query which returns a `LiveData<PagedList<Contact>>` of contacts stored in DB.

I want to modify this livedata before giving it to observers. Suppose there are ten contacts in the LiveData list, i want to do some comparison with another list and set which contacts are primary in the LiveData list.

After doing this i want to give it to observers .

e.g -

```
val allContacts: LiveData<PagedList<Contact>> = getFromDB()

val list: ArrayList<String>() = list of some primary contacts
```

traverse `allContacts` and `list` and set which values in `allContacts` match the values in `list`.
which ever values in `allContacts` match, their `isPrimary` property will be set to true.

Now after modifying `allContacts`, i want to submit it to observers like:

```
allContacts.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))
```

I tried LiveData.transform, But not able to use it properly.Can anyone suggest me how to achieve it using transform method or some other way.

Comment: `I tried LiveData.transform  But not able to use it properly`. Why? How? . `LiveData` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Transformation. Use [Transformations.map()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#map(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)) to create a new LiveData from a function that will be run everytime the first LiveData changes.

e.g.

```
val allContacts: LiveData<PagedList<Contact>> = getFromDB()
val contactViewModel = Transformations.map(allContacts, {
    // Transform and create new list from old
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rooted in the fact that you wish to "intercept" the updates that will be posted to the `LiveData` object by the DB. Regardless if this is a good approach you can technically achieve it by wrapping the `LiveData` that is returned by the DB with your own subclass of `LiveData`.

In other words. `UI` --observes--> `YourLiveData` --observes--> `DBLiveData`

P.S. I think genrally speaking you could solve your problem by modifying your DB query, but that is just me assuming you already have "primary contacts" in some other table